Generate pdf from ACF images
I'm facing a little problem. I just retrieved a client's site and my problem comes from printing.
To put it into context, here's what I have. Using ACF, image fields were set up on articles and then displayed in a slider. Except that the Print-O-matic extension which was installed (and removed from the Wordpress extensions since June 14) prints the slider pages, but there is a big shift on the right from the second page which makes the unreadable content.
Here is an example page : https://pianolimit.com/le-bemol/
My question is therefore: is it possible to recover these same image fields and create a pdf to print it and avoid the current problems.
I tried to change the extension but the problem now comes from the theme (Yootheme) which limits me in my choices in relation to the integration and I was not able to do it manually either.
Thanks for your help,
Nicolas

In order to avoid the shift problem, we can use a different approach that involves generating a PDF from the images directly. This can be done with a combination of a custom PHP function and a library like TCPDF or Dompdf.

Please install and download TCPDF and place it in your theme directory, e.g., your-theme/tcpdf. After this we need to create a Custom Template or Shortcode.
Please add the following code to your theme's functions.php or a custom plugin:
<?php
// Here we are including TCPDF library.
require_once get_template_directory() . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

// Need to register a shortcode for generating the PDF.
function generate_shortcode_pdf() {
    // Here we are retrieving the images from ACF fields.
    $images = get_field('your_acf_image_field'); // Adjust the field name as per your need.

    if (!$images) {
        return 'No images has been found.';
    }

    // Here we are creating new PDF document.
    $pdf = new TCPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // Here we are setting up the title of the document.
    $pdf->SetTitle('Image PDF');

    // Here we have added images to the PDF.
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $pdf->Image($image['url'], '', '', '', '', '', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
        $pdf->Ln();
    }

    // Here we are outputing the PDF.
    $pdf->Output('images.pdf', 'D'); // Here 'D' download, 'I' for inline display.
}
add_shortcode('generate_pdf', 'generate_shortcode_pdf');

